# Get unlimited tweets from twitter api

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweets

Is there a way that I can get unlimited or 500 tweets from Twitter?

I'm using python.

I can get 100 tweets by using `twitter_search = Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")` but it has a limitation on 100 tweets.

Edit:

Im using the pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.9.0 library.

It should be the public tweets and not the tweets from my account and my followers

Comment: What python package are you using ? (the one that provides the `Twitter` class)

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same issue.  As far as I can tell, there is really no getting around the twitter API limits, and there don't seem to be any other APIs that give access to archives of tweets.

One option, albeit a challenging one, is downloading all tweets in bulk from archive.org:

http://archive.org/details/twitterstream

Each month of data is > 30GB large though, compressed, so it won't be easy to handle.  But if you are determined, this will give you full control over the raw data with no limits.

Answer (score 2):

The twitter API limits the results to a maximum of 200 per request. How to set the count in your example to this maximum depends on the library you are using (which you didn't state, so I can't give you any information on that).

So, unlimited won't be possible in one request, no matter which library you are using.

See the "count" parameter here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline

Answer (score 0):

If you can shift to Orange from here you can get 9999 tweets per request. Hope someone will find it helpful.
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/twitter-sentiment-analysis-with-orange-vader-powerbi-part-1-184b693b9d70

[image]